# Change python cursor in IDLE

Tags: python, cursor, python-idle

I am using IDLE and Python 2.7.1.1.

I want to change the cursor from the blinking line (`|`) to the cursor of the Linux terminal when using IDLE. How can I do this?

Comment: The Python IDLE doesn't have that feature currently, I looked through all the documentation on IDLE preferences. If you _really_ wanted to do it you would have to find the IDLE's source code and modify it, as for its in Python using tk/tcl. However, you might not be able to do this because the code has already been compiled.

Comment: thanks , can we change it using the Tkinter module for our tk porgraoms

Comment: You really should look for an other editor. Have a look at sublime text (just the homepage, for starters ;D)

Comment: I use Atom Text Editor, it's free and well expanded among many languages. [Link here.](https://atom.io/) The only downside is that it's only windows, if you have Linux or Mac you have to use a VM.

Comment: @PrestonHager Lib/idlelib only contains .py files, no compiled .c files.  If a user changes one, the cached .pyc file is replaced.  In my answer, I detail where one could modify the IDLE source to change Text widget options that are not included in the Settings dialog.

Comment: @math2001  Syed did not ask for opinions on editors, and if he had, the question would have been marked as off-topic for Stackoverflow and possibly closed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by the 'the cursor of the Linux terminal'.  Is it necessarily the same for all Linux text programs?

In any case, tcl/tk Text widgets have one alternative insertion cursor, a blinking block.  (The insertion cursor is different from the mouse cursor.)  It can be seen by running this code (`root.mainloop()` might be needed if not running from IDLE).

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, blockcursor=True)
text.insert('insert', 'cursor appearance test')
text.pack()
text.focus_set()
```

If you backspace the cursor, the block blinks on top of and hides one of the characters.  To me, this is both ugly and misleading, in that insertion is always *between* characters and does not replace the char under the block.

However, if you want to experiment, you can edit idlelib/editor.py (or /EditorWindow.py before 3.6).  Find the part of EditorWindow.**init** that starts

```
text_options = {  # line 114 in 3.6
```

and add

```
    'blockcursor': True,
```

to the options dictionary.

Comment: Although this is a good answer for Tkinter cursors, @Syed asked how to do it with the Python IDLE.

Comment: @PrestonHager IDLE is written in tkinter and I answered how to change the tk Text cursor both generally *and in IDLE*.